# ClassNotFoundException - connectiong to MSSQL Database

Tags: android, sql-server, classnotfoundexception

I want to connect my android application to my MSSQL Database.
Unfortunately, there is a problem :/

> 10-25 19:17:00.536: W/System.err(18961): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
>   10-25 19:17:00.546: W/System.err(18961):    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
>   10-25 19:17:00.556: W/System.err(18961):    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:217)
>   10-25 19:17:00.556: W/System.err(18961):    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:172)
>   10-25 19:17:00.556: W/System.err(18961):    at com.example.mssqlcon.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:21)
>   10-25 19:17:00.556: W/System.err(18961):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
>   10-25 19:17:00.556: W/System.err(18961):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
>   10-25 19:17:00.556: W/System.err(18961):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2033)
>   10-25 19:17:00.556: W/System.err(18961):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2104)
>   10-25 19:17:00.556: W/System.err(18961):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:132)
>   10-25 19:17:00.556: W/System.err(18961):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1157)
>   10-25 19:17:00.556: W/System.err(18961):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   10-25 19:17:00.556: W/System.err(18961):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   10-25 19:17:00.566: W/System.err(18961):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4575)
>   10-25 19:17:00.566: W/System.err(18961):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   10-25 19:17:00.566: W/System.err(18961):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   10-25 19:17:00.566: W/System.err(18961):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
>   10-25 19:17:00.566: W/System.err(18961):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
>   10-25 19:17:00.566: W/System.err(18961):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   10-25 19:17:00.566: W/System.err(18961): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sourceforge/jtds/jdbc/Driver
>   10-25 19:17:00.566: W/System.err(18961):    ... 18 more
>   10-25 19:17:00.566: W/System.err(18961): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
>   10-25 19:17:00.576: W/System.err(18961):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
>   10-25 19:17:00.576: W/System.err(18961):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
>   10-25 19:17:00.576: W/System.err(18961):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
>   10-25 19:17:00.576: W/System.err(18961):    ... 18 more

My code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    try {
        Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();

        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://ip_of_my_database", "*****", "*******");
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        //ResultSet result = statement
        //      .executeQuery("SELECT * FROM nazwatabeli");
        ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM name");
        if(result.first()){
            do{
                Log.v("MainActivity", "Name: "+result.getString(result.getRow()));
            } while(result.next());

        }
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

What I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can't access SQL server directly using the Android device. You have to use a kind of a webservice to gain the access to a server which have the SQL connected. You can use java or php to do this. Check the following link for java webservices with android.

http://sarangasl.blogspot.com/2011/10/android-web-service-access-tutorial.html

What is the SDK version you are using? If it is r20 or upper you have to include all the external library files which you are using to lib folder inside the project through out your project. Otherwise it will tell ClassNotFoundException.
Tell me if you want any clarification.

Comment: r20? This is Api Level? My Api level is 8.

Comment: And really I can't acces to my MSSQL Database?

Comment: That is not about API. It is the SDK version. You can check it by opening Android SDK and the option about will tell you what the SDK version which you are using at the tools drop down.

Comment: This is not the way to access a external database. You have to use a server like apachy tomcat (for java) and create a webservice inside it. The link i provided includes all the basics for it. At the webservice you can use the database connecting code for SQL. If you want to use a internal storage use SQLite.